# How to get field of an object dynamically

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, schema, sobjecttype

I am trying to build a VF component. One of the feature of the component is the ability to show the fields related to an object dynamically. For example - if my component is used in an VF page like:

```
<apex:page controller="Acntrller">
<c:SampleComponent Record="Account"/>    
</apex:page>
```

Then I should be able to get the fields related to Account in the custom controller built for VF component.The VF component takes record type(object type) and assign it to a variable `controllerValue`, which is further used in my controller.

```
<apex:attribute name="record" description="The type of record we are viewing."
type="String" required="true" assignTo="{!controllerValue}"/>
```

`What I want:` I want a way to retrieve the fields of the object mentioned in the VF page `i.e. <c:SampleComponent Record="Account"/> ( Account object).`

`What I know:` I found that there is a way to get the fields using : `Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fields = Schema.SobjectType.Account.fields.getMap()` , but the problem here is it is 
static( the account part cannot be replaced with a variable- `controllerValue`) and I need something dynamic to get the fields.

Is there a way to get the fields of corresponding object dynamically?

Comment: Which *records* do you want to retrieve?

Comment: I get all the records of the object. I would like to retrieve fields of the object mentioned in : <c:SampleComponent Record="Account"/> . Ex- I want get the field of Account object.

Comment: Why not just use [`<apex:enhancedList type="Account" />`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_enhancedList.htm)?

Comment: @AdrianLarson `<apex:enhancedList>` doesn't support lightning exp and salesforce1 so personally I wouldn't recommend using it for now. I am planning to remove them from our projects.

Comment: My idea is to build a reusable component. I can specify any object and fetch the records of the object and show it as a list view. Also user has an ability to select the field which they want to view in the list view, There is more feature to this but this is a starting point of what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
String sobject_type = 'Account';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> global_describe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> object_fields_map = global_describe.get(sobject_type).getDescribe().fields.getMap();
```

Let me whether it resolves your issue.